# Allow users to create dynamic model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

In my `Rails3` app, I am using `ActiveRecord` and `Postgresql`.

Say I have a model called **Parts**.  The model has a small list of standard attributes such as price, quantity, etc.

However, Customer A might want to add `LotNumber` and CustomerB might want to add `OriginalLocation`.

How would I allow them to do that?

I thought about creating a **PartsDetail** model that allowed them to have a type.

```
class PartsDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :type, :value, :part_id
    belongs_to :parts
end
```

So that "type" could be "LotNumber", etc.

But I'm not quite sure how that would work in my associations and querying.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: For SQL: Either need a dynamic scheme (new columns), denormalization in a column (e.g. JSON), or a schema that represents the schema in the columns (e.g. EAV).

Comment: Employing customers as database designers is a really risky approach.

Comment: @Catcall Not necessarily "database designers" (this implies a much larger context than what this question is about). However, it is *quite common* to for a *business requirement* to attach additional "custom" properties to an entity. *Not allowing* this (in some fashion) can be negative towards business-specific needs. (In this case, CustomerB needs OriginalLocation.)

Comment: You might want to review PostgreSQL hstore values ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html ) and table inheritance ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-inheritance.html ) to refine your question.

Comment: @ps that's what I was imagining but I didn't know the name.

Comment: @pst that is exactly right.  My customers will want to add dynamic fields.  Right now, in my **other** job, we have to do it manually.  In Java.  Takes about 2-4 hours to add one field.  My version is going to easier.  :-)

Comment: @pst: I know the arguments. I've seen "dynamic fields" work well exactly once since 1985. That was in a system I designed to support international litigation. In that case, there were strong administrative constraints (not database constraints) on data entry. Those constraints effectively made those dynamic fields a single-user system. The single user was a lawyer, and only two paralegals were allowed to add anything to the dynamic fields. Without strong administrative control, you end up with a dozen different variations of OriginalLocation, and nobody can find things when they need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using PostgreSQL, you could use [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) to store arbitrary hashes in database columns:

> This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. This can be useful in various scenarios, such as rows with many attributes that are rarely examined, or semi-structured data. Keys and values are simply text strings.

There's even a gem for adding `hstore` support to ActiveRecord:

> https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Then you could create an `hstore` column called, say, `client_specific` and look inside it with things like:

```
M.where("client_specific -> 'likes' = 'pancakes'")
M.where("client_specific @> 'likes=>pancakes'")
```

to see which clients have noted that they like pancakes.

You might want to store a list of customer-specific fields somewhere with the customer record to make the UI side of things easier to deal with but that's pretty simple to do.

Comment: Would this approach be better than an EAV solution or is it the same thing?  The dynamic attributes that are needed are much more than "rarely examined".  They are key to their model.  Thanks

Comment: @cbmeeks: This isn't quite the same as EAV, this basically adds string-to-string Hashes as a column type. You don't need an extra table or a join for this and unlike the various `serialize` approaches, `hstore` columns are fully indexable just like anything else. PostgreSQL also has a suite of functions and operators specifically for `hstore` so they might be easier than doing it all by hand through EAV.

Comment: Decent blog post on using hstore in rails: http://neilmiddleton.com/the-wonders-of-hstore/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a gist that someone wrote that allows you to use hstore attributes in your models more seamlessly:  https://gist.github.com/2834785

To use add this in an initializer ( or create a new initializer called active_record_extensions.rb )

```
require "hstore_accessor"
```

Then in your model you can have:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  hstore_accessor :properties, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

That allows you to do:

```
u = User.new
u.first_name = 'frank'
```

You can still do add attributes to the hstore column and bypass the hstore_attributes though:

```
u.properties['middle_name'] = 'danger'
```